# Error File name too long Yocto Project

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I'm working on a Yocto project, 
Version : poky-jethro

I want to build a version of the distribution poky to Raspberry Pi

```
Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION        = "1.28.0"
BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING   = "Ubuntu-14.04"
TARGET_SYS        = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE           = "raspberrypi"
DISTRO            = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION    = "2.0.1"
TUNE_FEATURES     = "arm armv6 vfp arm1176jzfs callconvention-hard"
TARGET_FPU        = "vfp"
meta              
meta-yocto        = "jethro:3b223f75eec1738fbc913858e8e11c8305e3edcb"
meta-oe           
meta-multimedia   
meta-networking   
meta-python       = "jethro:c305ac5d2f5285d5eec8952a4ca7f3b4f89aed96"
meta-qt5          = "jethro:9bfcf79fcd824efb9f2a9bd72ecbedfee1315c96"
meta-raspberrypi  = "jethro:f2cff839f52a6e6211337fc45c7c3eabf0fac113"
meta-rpi          = "jethro:3ef71867eeb3669da40019469385a437843e8245"
```

I succeeded in building system on another OS "Ubuntu-14.0403"
but when I tried build system on another version "Ubuntu-14.0404"

This error appears

[Errno 36] File name too long

[[Errno 36] File name too long](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tATF.png)

Comment: There is supposed to be a sanity check which detects this problem and warns users that it won't work on those encrypted filesystems. It seems you didn't hit this and we looked into why but couldn't reproduce the problem. Is there a way we can reproduce this error so we can give a better message to users? Do you have any more context on the error you saw?

Comment: I When installed a new copy of Ubuntu I checked the box in front of encrypted home folder label

When I built the system Sanity warns me and  detect  this problem, but I did not understand what it meant in the beginning

But beyond this warning when i copy a file sanity_info from  conf folder that is generated when i build the system properly in old OS before this problem occurs and paste it in the same folder on the new OS, which you select the option to encrypt the home folder for him

for this reason sanity did not detect the problem at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks, that at east confirms the check did work as expected. Bypassing those tests isn't recommended, they show warnings for a reason!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably selected the option when installing Ubuntu to use encrypted home directories, which unfortunately uses a broken file system that can't handle long file names. If this is the case it's best to reinstall Ubuntu without encrypted home directories (or any other distro as they generally do disk encryption properly)

Comment: I will re-install the operating system and tell you if you exceed this problem

Comment: if other distros don't have this problem. What needs to be fixed in Ubuntu to get this resolved? I want my home encrypted. I hope not to have to reinstall

Comment: Ubuntu explictly uses ecryptfs to offer encrypted per-user home directories. Because of how that works, you can't build Yocto in it (because it doesn't allow long files).